# TinyXML2/C++ - Insert an element

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml2

I wanted to serialize objects with XML, so I got TinyXML. However I went with the newer TinyXML2. Problem is, I can't find a tutorial anywhere, so I just read the documentation. However, I seem to be stuck with adding an element to the document.

Could someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Here's my `demo.xml` file contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Hello>World</Hello>
```

here's my `main()` method:

```
#include "tinyxml2/tinyxml2.h"
using namespace tinyxml2;

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) 
{
   XMLDocument doc;
   if (doc.LoadFile("demo.xml") == XML_SUCCESS)
   {
      XMLNode *node = doc.NewElement("foo");
      doc.InsertEndChild(node);
      doc.SaveFile("demo2.xml");
   }
}
```

and finally, here's the `demo2.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Hello>World</Hello>

<foo/>
```

Foo should look like this: `<foo></foo>`

But it doesn't for some reason. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: what do you want your xml file to look like on successful write?

Comment: You know that `<foo/>` and `<foo></foo>` is equivalent? I would guess as soon as you add some text to your node tinyxml will change to the later.

Comment: oh... i suppose I should brush up on XML syntax...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, it shouldn't look like that. You don't put any data "in between" your `<foo>...</foo>` tags. As such `<foo/>` (note the slash) is a correct representation of what you have.

Answer (score 4):

between if, you may modify your code as follow:

```
XMLElement *node = doc.NewElement("foo");
XMLText *text = doc.NewText("Another Hello!");    
node->LinkEndChild(text);     
doc.LinkEndChild(node);

doc.SaveFile("demo2.xml");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the SetText() function to add blank content so that you can achieve the desired effect

```
XMLNode *node = doc.NewElement("foo");
node->SetText("");
doc.InsertEndChild(node);
doc.SaveFile("demo2.xml");
```